# How do I condense multiple similar hotkeys into one in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create hotkeys to simulate input buffering in an online game I'm playing which doesn't natively support input buffering, meaning mashing a spell key so that it goes off after the previous spell is finished casting is the best method to manually do.

With the help of a hotkey I can loop the key press with minimal delay by holding down my key so that it sends the instant I'm done casting the previous spell.

However creating multiple hotkeys for each button I have bound on my keyboard to a spell seems tedious and I'm not sure how to condense these hotkeys into one using an array of defined keys (ie. 1 through 6, and F1 through F6)

An example snippet of my code so far with only 3 keys taken into account:

```
$5::
{
    Loop
    {
        Loop, 5
        {
            Send, 5
            Sleep, 1
        }
        GetKeyState, state, 5
        if state = U
            break
    }
    return
}

$2::
{
    Loop
    {
        Loop, 5
        {
            Send, 2
            Sleep, 1
        }
        GetKeyState, state, 2
        if state = U
            break
    }
    return
}

$F2::
{
    Loop
    {
        Loop, 5
        {
            Send, {F2}
            Sleep, 1
        }
        GetKeyState, state, F2
        if state = U
            break
    }
    return
}
```

I'm trying to condense it to something like this, if possible:

```
hotkeys := [5, 2, F2]
hotkeyCount := hotkeys.MaxIndex()
curKey := 1

Loop, hotkeyCount
{
    hotkeyIndex := hotkeys[curKey]
    $%hotkeyIndex%::
    {
        Loop
        {
            Loop, 5
            {
                Send, {%hotkeyIndex%}
                Sleep, 1
            }
            GetKeyState, state, %hotkeyIndex%
            if state = U
                break
        }
        return
    }
    curKey := curKey + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a FIFO stack that will safe the preset actions and call them when they are ready.

Array `functions` contains the functions: `Function_a`, `Function_b`, `Function_c`,  that are triggered with their respective hotkeys, `a`, `b`, `c`.
The hotkeys don't call the functions directly, but add their numerical index the to the stack `stack`.

The timer `check`, retrieves the numerical index from the `stack`, then the function from the array `functions` at that index is called. When the function returns, the next index is retrieved if there is any. Only one functions is running at a time.

```
SetBatchLines, -1

global stack := Object()
global stack_head = 0
global stack_tail = 0
global functions := [Func("Function_a"),Func("Function_b"),Func("Function_c")]

SetTimer, check , 25

return

check:
    if( stack_head > stack_tail )
    {
        i := stack[stack_tail]
        functions[i]()
        stack_tail++
    }
return  

Function_a()
{
    tooltip, Function_a running...
    Sleep, 1000
    tooltip, 
    return
}

Function_b()
{
    tooltip, Function_b running...
    Sleep, 1000
    tooltip,
    return
}

Function_c()
{
    tooltip, Function_c running...
    Sleep, 1000
    return
}

a::
    stack[stack_head] := 1
    stack_head++
return

s::
    stack[stack_head] := 2
    stack_head++
return

d::
    stack[stack_head] := 3
    stack_head++
return
```

This enables concurrent running of the functions, that can do whatever you want, while at the same time hotkeys can add actions (functions indexes) to the stack, which will be called in order they were added one at a time.

---

I have edited you example to make it functional:

```
$a::
$s::
$d::
$1::

key := A_ThisHotkey
key :=Trim(key,"$")
Loop
{
    Loop, 5
    {
        SendInput, %key%
        Sleep, 1
    }
    state := GetKeyState(key , "P" )
    if state = 0
    {
        break
    }
}

return
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating individual lines for each keybind? This doesn't seem to be condensed at all unless I'm missing something... I don't mind if keys can't be held down together, I mind making 16 different hotkeys rather than just inputting a letter into an array to add that key to my script

Comment: @Erin You have to write the hotkeys, how will you otherwise get different actions? You do that in your example where you define 3 hotkeys and some actions they perform. Given their size in lines, my example is actually more compact.

Comment: I edited my post, perhaps my example is better clarification than me trying to explain what I'm attempting to accomplish with language

Comment: @Erin See the update. I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for.